# Laravel 6 showing white blank page instead of error message

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

**if i make any kinds of error in my view page it is not showing error message.**

Suppose, I have a collection of data which is assigned in **$data** variable and then if i try to get result from **$da** (actual assigned variable is $data) from dd function it is showing blank white page instead of error message.
[image]
please! anyone can suggest me how can i get this..?

Comment: Even if you're getting a plane white page, the error log located in `project_directory/logs` should show the error that you are getting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: Have you turned on your debugging mode from .env file `APP_DEBUG=true` ?

Comment: yes , definitely